# How to auto align controls with Windows Forms

Tags: winforms

I have a simple form with a label inside and I changed the label font and size. Every time that I run the program the label gets out of the forms even trying to set the `ContentAlignment.TopCenter`. How can I make the label adjust to the current window?

Cs :

```
 InitializeComponent();
 this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
 this.MaximizeBox = false;
 this.label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 27, FontStyle.Regular);
 this.label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
 label1.Text = "AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD";
```

[image]

Comment: TextAlign doesn't do anything useful when you leave the AutoSize property set to True.  You probably meant to set its Anchor property, hard to tell when it is so contrived.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the label1's location property was set

Reset the location property to 0 using the Properties window or using the below line of code.

`this.label1.Location = new Point(0, 0);`